# Sklearn regression with label encoding

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, one-hot-encoding

I'm attempting to use sklearn's linear regression model to predict fantasy players points. I have numeric stats for each player and obviously their name which I have encoded with the Label encoder function. My question is when performing the linear regression the encoded values included in the training it doesn't seem to recognize it as an ID but instead treats it as a numeric value.

So is there a better way to encode player names so they are treated as an ID so that it recognizes player 1 averages 25 points compared to player 2's 20? Or is this type of encoding even possible with linear regression? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Apart from one hot encoding (which might create way too many columns in this case), mean target encoding does exactly what you need (encodes the category with its mean target value). You should be vary about the target leakage in case of rare categories though. sklearn-compatible `category_encoders` library provides several robust implementations, such as [LeaveOneOutEncoder()](https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/category_encoders/leaveoneout.html)